# Why is my Timer2 interrupt not working? Am I missing any register configs?

Tags: c, pic, mplab

I am working on a project with the pic10f322 microcontroller. I've made a very basic communication protocol - there is a start pulse (10 ms) followed by a number of 5ms pulses (2 pulses - turns on a red light, 3 turns on yellow and 4 - green). So the following code is trying to read the communication protocol and turn on the respective light. I'm using TMR0 to measure the length of the pulse and count it. I have a bicolour LED (Red and Green) so I need to alternate the two to create the yellow. I was hoping to use TMR2 as an interrupt to allow me to pulse the yellow light separately from the rest of the code, so that it doesn't get in the way of my main function detecting start pulses.

I have no idea why it isn't working. I've checked the registers (although please do double check incase I'm blind to something). The code compiles.
I turned the light on at various stages of the code to check it, and the light turns on in every case statement, include the last one where I set the LedColour enum variable to the respective colour. When I try to turn the light on in the interrupt function, it never turns on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pic10f322.h>

// crystal oscilator 
define _XTAL_FREQ 1000000

 // CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection bits 
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset disabled
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // WDT disabled
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // PWRT disabled
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR pin function
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection disabled
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-voltage programming enabled
#pragma config LPBOR = OFF      // Brown-out Reset disabled
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage, low trip point
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Write protection off

void timer2_isr(void);

#pragma code high_vector=0x08;
void interrupt (void)
{
    asm("GOTO timer2_isr");
}
#pragma code

#pragma interrupt timer2_isr

#define RED_LED    0x01
#define GREEN_LED  0x02

#define SetBit(bit) (PORTA |= bit )
#define ClearBit(bit) (PORTA &= ~bit)
#define TestBit(bit)   ( PORTA&bit)

int clkval = 0;

int pulsecnt = 0;

    enum {
        Red,
        Green,
        Yellow,
        Off,
    } LedColor = Off;


void timer2_isr (void)
{
    PORTA = 0b1101; //This turns a green light on if it enters this function
    if (PIR1 == 0x02)
    {
        PIR1 = 0x00;
    }
}


void main(int argc, char** argv) 
{    
    OSCCON = 0x30; //1MHz Clk
    TRISA = 0x0C;
    ANSELA = 0x00;
    PORTA = 0x0C;
    OPTION_REG = 0x06;
    T2CON = 0x04; //Timer2 Registers Prescaler= 1 - TMR2 PostScaler = 1 - PR2 = 254 - Freq = 980.39 Hz - Period = 0.001020 seconds
    PIE1 = 0x02;
    PIR1 = 0x00;
    TMR0 = 0;
    TMR2 = 0;
    PR2 = 254;
    INTCON = 0xC0;

    __delay_ms(2000);

    enum {
        WaitForStart,
        CountPulses,
        SelectColor,
    } State = WaitForStart;

    while (1) 
    {
        switch (State) 
        {
            case WaitForStart: //wait for start pulse
                if ( (PORTA & 0x04) != 0x04 )
                {
                    TMR0 = 0;
                    while ((PORTA & 0x04) != 0x04) 
                    {
                        clkval = TMR0;
                    }
                    if (18 < clkval < 22)
                    {
                        State = CountPulses;
                        pulsecnt = 0;
                    } 
                }
                break;

            case CountPulses: // found start pulse, now count pulses or reset
                if ( (PORTA & 0x04) != 0x04 )
                {
                    TMR0 = 0;
                    while ((PORTA & 0x04) != 0x04) 
                    {
                        clkval = TMR0;
                    }
                    if (8 < clkval < 12)
                    {
                        pulsecnt++;
                    }
                }
                if ((PORTA & 0x04) == 0x04)
                {
                    clkval = 0;
                    TMR0 = 0;

                    while ((PORTA & 0x04) == 0x04 && clkval < 45) 
                    {
                        clkval = TMR0;
                        if ((44 < clkval) || (pulsecnt > 4)) //no pulses noticed in over 22ms comparison or if you have surpassed the max number of pulses you are supposed to reach
                        {
                            if (pulsecnt > 0) 
                            { 
                                State = SelectColor;                             
                            } //if there has been a long delay,  and pulses have been detect (so pulsecnt is greater than 0) then move to next case
                            else 
                            {
                                State = WaitForStart;
                            } // if long delay and no pulses have been detected, restart and check for start pulse again
                        } 
                    }
                }
                break;

            case SelectColor: // if pulses have been detected, this state will be visited after long delay ( >22ms)

                if (pulsecnt == 2) 
                {
                    LedColor = Red;
                    //PORTA = 0b1110;
                    State = WaitForStart;
                }
                else if (pulsecnt == 3) 
                {
                    LedColor = Yellow;
                    State = WaitForStart;
                } 
                else if (pulsecnt == 4)
                {
                    LedColor = Green;
                    //PORTA = 0b1101;
                    State = WaitForStart;
                }
                else 
                {
                    LedColor = Off; 
                    State = WaitForStart;
                }
                break;

            default:
                State = WaitForStart;
                break;
        }

    } 
}
```

I used "PORTA = 0b1101", which turns the green light on. as a test line to step through the code and make sure it's reach certain points. Right now it is at the beginning of the interrupt, so it should turn on and stay on righht after the first interrupt which would happen within approximately 2.5ms I think? Or relatively quickly anyway, but it never gets inside the interrupt function or the function before which uses assembly to tell it to goto this function.

Comment: I used a PIC decades ago for some projects. Later, one student stumbled over the watchdog setting (a check box in the PIC programming UI). He had his watchdog on and his program did a "strange loop" he could not explain until I showed him this watchdog setting and he turned off the watchdog. Maybe you also "got lucky" :)

Comment: @BitTickler unfortunately I don't think I'm that lucky, my watchdog is off already :( but I appreciate you sharing your experience as I'm sure I could easily have made that mistake, I've very much a beginner with PICs!

Comment: there is also some stuff producing warnings, such as e.g. ``if (18 < clkval < 22)`` (happens multiple time in code) "somain.c:106:37: warning: comparison of constant 22 with boolean expression is always true [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]" and some other things. I compiled using the online IDE of MPLab. https://mplabxpress.microchip.com/mplabcloud/ide

Answer (score 1):

In PIC16, you need to start the timer separately from the rest of the config, like that:

`T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1;`

Also, check that you have enabled the interrupts:

```
INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;
INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
```

I suggest using the above notation for initialization; what you have is hard to verify.

Answer (score 0):

The PIC 10 has got only one interrupt vector and that is on address `0x04` (not `0x08` as you expected).

Try somethig like this:

```
void interrupt myISR(void)
{
........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This init function gets a TMR2 interrupting at high priority
on a PIC18F25K80

```
void pwm_mosfet_stepper_init() {
    
    TMR2 = 0;
    RCON |= (1<<7);    // IPEN = 1;
    PR2 = 100; // 100; // 100==@16uS 1.6ms
    //       
    INTCON |= ( (1<<6) | (1<<7) ); // GIE/GIEH PEIE/GIEL i.e. both low and high enabled
     
    // .......................... post4  ON pre4
    //T2CON = 0x1D; // 2us tick ON   11    1  01

    // .......................... post4  ON pre16
    T2CON = 0x1F; // 16us tick ON   11    1  1X

    IPR1 |= (1<<1); // TMR2IP = 1; HIGH PRIORITY
    PIE1 |= (1<<1); // TMR2IE = 1; // interrupts are GO!
}
```